# Replicating a tricky roadmap design with vertical bars on LaTeX

Tags: vertical-alignment, boxes, timeline

I've been writing my own class for a document, mostly because the document uses several unconventional design requirements, and I though writing a class from scratch would be better than adapting an existing one. So far I've managed pretty much every design requirement, but now I'm having trouble replicating the following:

[image]

The problem is obviously with the colored vertical lines. The rest I believe I can manage. Here's what I have right now:

[image]

Font formatting, colors, spacing, margins, and so on, don't really matter yet, what I'm trying to do is achieve those longer, darker, lines that represent the year. Although I'm posting the whole class, the important is the `roadmap` environment at the bottom, where everything else is defined. Here's the class:

```
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Identification
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesClass{whitepaper}[2018/01/01 White Paper LaTeX class]

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Defaults
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\RequirePackage{ifthen}

\newboolean{twoside}
\setboolean{twoside}{false}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Options
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\DeclareOption{twoside}{
    \setboolean{twoside}{true}
}
\ProcessOptions\relax

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Geometry
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\RequirePackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\geometry{
    a4paper,
    textheight=750pt,
    headsep=50pt,
    voffset=0pt,
    top=30pt,
    left=20mm,
    right=20mm,
}\savegeometry{covergeometry}

\geometry{
    a4paper,
    textheight=650pt,
    headsep=50pt,
    voffset=0pt,
    top=95pt,
    left=61mm,
    right=39mm
}\savegeometry{evenpagegeometry}

\geometry{
    a4paper,
    textheight=650pt,
    headsep=50pt,
    voffset=0pt,
    top=95pt,
    left=20mm,
    right=20mm
}\savegeometry{sectiongeometry}

\geometry{
    a4paper,
    textheight=650pt,
    headsep=50pt,
    voffset=0pt,
    top=95pt,
    left=39mm,
    right=61mm
}\savegeometry{oddpagegeometry}

\geometry{
    a4paper,
    textheight=650pt,
    headsep=50pt,
    voffset=0pt,
    top=95pt,
    left=39mm,
    right=50mm
}\savegeometry{tocgeometry}

\geometry{
    a4paper,
    textheight=650pt,
    headsep=50pt,
    voffset=0pt,
    top=95pt,
    left=39mm,
    right=61mm
}\savegeometry{chaptergeometry}

\geometry{
    a4paper,
    textheight=650pt,
    headsep=50pt,
    voffset=0pt,
    top=95pt,
    left=20mm,
    right=20mm
}\savegeometry{defaultgeometry}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Multilingual support
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\RequirePackage[english]{babel}
\RequirePackage{csquotes}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Colors
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{fmtcount}

\definecolor{primarycolor}{RGB}{47,53,61}
\definecolor{secondarycolor}{RGB}{152,160,171}
\definecolor{terciarycolor}{RGB}{151,159,172}
\definecolor{covercolor}{RGB}{46,53,61}
\definecolor{highlightcolor}{RGB}{34,104,249}
\definecolor{casecolor}{RGB}{0,232,163}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% SI units, used for money representations as well
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\RequirePackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{
    group-four-digits = true,
    group-separator = {,}
}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Font
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\RequirePackage[sfdefault]{roboto}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}

\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{10pt}{14pt}\selectfont}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
    \color{primarycolor}\global\let\default@color\current@color
}
\makeatother

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Paragraphs
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{15pt}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Double pages
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\blankpage}{
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \newpage
}

\newcommand{\vacatpage}{
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{twoside}}{\blankpage\blankpage}{\newpage}
}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Cover page
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\RequirePackage{authoraftertitle}
\RequirePackage{pagecolor}
\RequirePackage{afterpage}
\RequirePackage[export]{adjustbox}

\newcommand{\maketitle}{
    \loadgeometry{covergeometry}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \newpagecolor{covercolor}
    \afterpage{\restorepagecolor}
    \includegraphics[width=200pt,right]{logo-h-white}
    {
        \color{white}
        \fontseries{k}
        \fontsize{45pt}{60pt}
        \selectfont
        {
            \vspace*{25pt}
            \newline
            \MyTitle
            \par
        }
    }
}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Utilities
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\twodigits}[1]{
    \ifnum#1<10 0#1\else #1\fi
}

\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{thepage}{\def\thepage{\arabic{page}}}{}%
\makeatother

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Copyright
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\makecopyright}{
    \vacatpage
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \centerline{Copyright {\copyright} {\the\year}}
    \centerline{All rights reserved.}
}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Table of Contents
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\maketoc}{
    \vacatpage
    \loadgeometry{tocgeometry}
    \vspace*{5pt}
    {
        \fontseries{k}
        \fontsize{25pt}{25pt}
        \selectfont
        {Table of contents}
        \vspace{50pt}
        \newline
    }
    \@starttoc{toc}
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\addchaptertocline}[2]{
    \addtocontents{toc}
    {
        \makebox[50pt][l] { % Numbering
            \fontsize{24pt}{24pt}\selectfont\color{primarycolor}\textbf{\unexpanded{\unexpanded{\twodigits}}{\thechapter}}
        }
        % Title
        \fontsize{10pt}{10pt}\selectfont\color{highlightcolor}\textbf{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
        \hfill\color{terciarycolor}\textbf{\thepage}
        \par
        { % Description
            \parindent=52.5pt
            \hangindent=52.5pt
            \parbox{200pt}{
                \fontsize{9}{12pt}\selectfont\color{secondarycolor}{#2}\\
            }
            \par
        }
    }
}

\newcommand{\addsectiontocline}[2]{
    \addtocontents{toc}
    {
        {
            \parindent=52.5pt
            \hangindent\parindent
            \fontsize{10pt}{15pt}
            \selectfont
            \color{primarycolor}\textbf{#1}
            \hfill\color{terciarycolor}\textbf{\thepage}
            \strut
            \newline
            \parbox{200pt}{
                \strut
                \color{terciarycolor}#2
            }
            \par
        }
    }
}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Styles
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage{everypage}

\ifthenelse{\boolean{twoside}}
{
%   \fancyheadoffset[leh,roh]{70pt}
%   \fancyheadoffset[loh,reh]{65pt}
}
{
%   \fancyheadoffset[le]{135pt}
%   \fancyheadoffset[ro]{135pt}
%   \fancyfootoffset[le]{135pt}
%   \fancyfootoffset[ro]{135pt}
}

\fancypagestyle{printchaptertitle}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \chaptermarginals
    \setlength{\footskip}{43pt}
    \rfoot{\color{secondarycolor}\thepage}
}

\fancypagestyle{printchaptercontents}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \chaptermarginals
    \rhead{\color{secondarycolor}\thepage}
}

\fancypagestyle{printsectiontitle}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \sectionmarginals
    \rhead{\color{secondarycolor}\thepage}
}

\fancypagestyle{printsectioncontents}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \sectionmarginals
    \rhead{\color{secondarycolor}\thepage}
}

\newcommand{\chaptermarginals}{
    \fancyheadoffset[ro]{135pt}
    \fancyheadoffset[re]{135pt}
    \fancyfootoffset[re]{135pt}
    \fancyfootoffset[ro]{135pt}
}

\newcommand{\sectionmarginals}{
    \fancyheadoffset[re]{18pt}
    \fancyheadoffset[ro]{18pt}
}

% There's never a head rule
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Chapters
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcounter{chapter}
\newcommand{\chaptername}{\null}
\newcommand{\chapter}[2]{
    \vacatpage
    \renewcommand{\chaptername}{#1}
    \refstepcounter{chapter}
    \loadgeometry{chaptergeometry}
    \chapterstyle
    \vspace*{45pt} % Empty space
    \par
    { % Numbering
        \fontsize{24pt}{50pt}
        \fontseries{k}
        \selectfont
        \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
        \hspace*{-70pt}
        \color{secondarycolor}
        \twodigits{\thechapter}
        \vspace{19pt}
        \par
    }
    { % Title
        \fontsize{44pt}{39pt}
        \fontseries{k}
        \selectfont
        \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
        \color{primarycolor}
        \hspace*{-75pt}
        \vspace*{30pt}
        #1
    }
    \fontsize{10pt}{13pt}
    \selectfont
    % ToC
    \addchaptertocline{#1}{#2}
}

\newcommand{\chapterstyle}{
    \pagestyle{printchaptercontents}
    \thispagestyle{printchaptertitle}
}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Sections
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\RequirePackage{multicol}

\newcounter{section}
\newcommand{\sectionname}{\null}
\newcommand{\section}[2]{
    \newpage
    \loadgeometry{sectiongeometry}
    \sectionstyle
    \fontsize{10pt}{14pt}
    \selectfont
    \vspace*{90pt}
    { % Chapter name
        \color{secondarycolor}
        \MakeUppercase{\chaptername}
        \par
    }
    { % Title
        \setlength{\parskip}{10pt}
        \fontsize{44pt}{44pt}
        \fontseries{k}
        \selectfont
        \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
        \color{primarycolor}
        {#1}
        \par
    }
    \vspace*{30pt}
    % ToC
    \addsectiontocline{#1}{#2}
    \setlength{\columnsep}{20pt}
}

\newcommand{\sectionstyle}{
    \pagestyle{printsectioncontents}
    \thispagestyle{printsectiontitle}
}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Conditional content
%
% \contentlevel impacts the output of \cont by filtering content that is of a level greater
% than the given threshold. Such content does not appear on the output, while everything
% else does. The level also applies to citations. Content levels are defined as follows:
%
%   0       Minimal         Doesn't print any conditional content
%   1       Basic           Prints basic content
%   2       Overview        Prints enough content for a general overview
%   3       Technical       Prints technical content
%   4       Enterprise      Prints all content except private
%   5       Private         Prints all content
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\def\contentlevel#1{
    \def\contentlevel_{#1}
}

\def\contentif#1{
    \expandafter\contentiff#1\relax
}

\def\contentiff#1,#2\relax{
    \ifnum\contentlevel_ < 1
        % nop
    \else
        \ifnum\numexpr#1-1 < \contentlevel_\relax#2\fi
    \fi
}

\def\citeif#1{
    \expandafter\citeiff#1\relax
}

\def\citeiff#1,#2\relax{
    \ifnum\numexpr#1-1 < \contentlevel_\relax\supercite{#2}\fi
}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Quotes
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\highlight}[2]{
    \begingroup
        \fontsize{13pt}{17pt}
        \selectfont
        \begin{flushleft}
            \textbf{\color{secondarycolor}"\color{highlightcolor}#2\color{secondarycolor}"}
        \end{flushleft}
    \endgroup
    \begingroup
        \fontsize{11pt}{11pt}
        \selectfont
        \color{secondarycolor}\textbf{#1}
    \endgroup
}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% State of the technology
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\RequirePackage{vwcol}

\newcommand{\sot}[1]{
    \vfill
    \begin{multicols}{3}
        \color{highlightcolor}
        \begingroup
            \begin{flushright}
                \textbf{State of the techonolgy}
                \hspace{3pt}
                \rule[-5pt]{1pt}{15pt}
                \vfill\null
                \columnbreak
            \end{flushright}
        \endgroup
        \begingroup
            \begin{flushleft}
                #1
            \end{flushleft}
        \endgroup
    \end{multicols}
}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Case lists
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\RequirePackage{mdframed}

% innerbottommargin=-2pt
\newmdenv[topline=false,rightline=false,bottomline=false,linecolor=casecolor,linewidth=2pt]{caselistleftborder}

\newenvironment{caselist}[1]{
    \vspace*{25pt}
    \begin{caselistleftborder}
        {
            \fontsize{11pt}{0pt}
            \fontseries{b}
            \selectfont
            \color{secondarycolor}
            \MakeUppercase{\chaptername}
            \par
        }
        { % Title
            \fontsize{25pt}{0pt}
            \fontseries{b}
            \selectfont
            \textbf{#1}
        }
    \end{caselistleftborder}
    \setlength{\columnsep}{20pt}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
}{
    \end{multicols}
}

\newcommand{\casetitle}[1]{
    \vspace*{30pt}
    \begin{flushleft}
        \fontsize{17pt}{21pt}
        \selectfont
        \color{primarycolor}
        \textbf{#1}
    \end{flushleft}
        \setlength{\parskip}{5pt}
\par
}

\newcommand{\casesubtitle}[1]{
    \fontsize{11pt}{0pt}
    \selectfont
    \color{primarycolor}
    \textbf{#1}
    \setlength{\parskip}{15pt}
    \par
}

\newcommand{\casecontents}[1]{
    \fontsize{11pt}{15pt}
    \selectfont
    \color{secondarycolor}
    #1
}

\newcommand{\case}[3]{
    \begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
        \casetitle{#1}
        \casesubtitle{#2}
        \casecontents{#3}
    \end{minipage}
}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Roadmap
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newmdenv[topline=false,rightline=false,bottomline=false,linecolor=casecolor,linewidth=6pt]{roadmayearborder}

\newenvironment{roadmap}{

    \newenvironment{releaseyear}[1]{
%       \mbox{
%           \fontsize{23pt}{0pt}
%           \fontseries{k}
%           \selectfont
%           \rotatebox{90}{##1}
%       }
    }{
    }

    \newenvironment{releasequarter}[1]{
        \mbox{
            \fontsize{13pt}{0pt}
            \fontseries{b}
            \selectfont
            ##1
        }
    }{
    }

    \newcommand{\release}[2]{
        \begin{roadmayearborder}
            \mbox{##1}
            \hspace*{\fill}
            \mbox{##2}
        \end{roadmayearborder}
    }
}{
}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Bibliography
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\RequirePackage[backend=bibtex,sorting=none,autocite=superscript]{biblatex}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\supercite}[\mkbibsuperscript]
{\iffieldundef{prenote}
    {}
    {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
    \iffieldundef{postnote}
    {}
    {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}%
    \bibopenbracket}%
{\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \usebibmacro{cite}}
{\supercitedelim}
{\bibclosebracket}
```

And here's the document:

```
\documentclass{whitepaper}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Roadmap}

\begin{roadmap}

    \begin{releaseyear}{2016}

        \begin{releasequarter}{Q1}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
        \end{releasequarter}

        \begin{releasequarter}{Q2}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
        \end{releasequarter}

        \begin{releasequarter}{Q3}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
        \end{releasequarter}

        \begin{releasequarter}{Q4}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
        \end{releasequarter}

    \end{releaseyear}
\end{roadmap}
\end{document}
```

How can I achieve the desired effect?

As requested, here's a standalone version, without the class, but I couldn't reproduce the same output. Even with `\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}` the lines still show differently:

```
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Preamble
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{10pt}{14pt}\selectfont}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\geometry{
    a4paper,
    textheight=650pt,
    headsep=50pt,
    voffset=0pt,
    top=95pt,
    left=39mm,
    right=61mm
}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Roadmap
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{mdframed}

\newmdenv[topline=false,rightline=false,bottomline=false,linecolor=black,linewidth=6pt]{roadmayearborder}

\newenvironment{roadmap}{

    \newenvironment{releaseyear}[1]{
        %       \mbox{
        %           \fontsize{23pt}{0pt}
        %           \fontseries{k}
        %           \selectfont
        %           \rotatebox{90}{##1}
        %       }
    }{
    }

    \newenvironment{releasequarter}[1]{
        \mbox{
            \fontsize{13pt}{0pt}
            \fontseries{b}
            \selectfont
            ##1
        }
    }{
    }

    \newcommand{\release}[2]{
        \begin{roadmayearborder}
            \mbox{##1}
            \hspace*{\fill}
            \mbox{##2}
        \end{roadmayearborder}
    }
}{
}


\begin{document}

\begin{roadmap}
    \begin{releaseyear}{2016}
        \begin{releasequarter}{Q1}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
        \end{releasequarter}
        \begin{releasequarter}{Q2}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
        \end{releasequarter}
        \begin{releasequarter}{Q3}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
        \end{releasequarter}
        \begin{releasequarter}{Q4}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
        \end{releasequarter}
    \end{releaseyear}
\end{roadmap}

\end{document}
```

This produces the following output:
[image]

Comment: Is a TikZ solution acceptable?

Comment: I guess... Will it adjust to document changes and such? I've never used TikZ before.

Comment: What I have in mind would be something along the lines of [List environment with vertical lines along nested lists](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/270939) but the page breaking might be a problem.

Comment: Indeed. In the first option the lines just disappear after inserting a certain number of elements. The second is using `tcolorbox`, which I already tried; I had the same problem, when a page overflow occurs, the next is just moved to a new page. But it already helps, as I couldn't achieve only left borders before!

Comment: Just a comment about your question itself. Since the problem doesn't really relate to the class per se, (as you note) it might be easier to just create a sample document with article class and the relevant environments defined within rather than have it depend on the class.

Comment: Sounds good! I previously posted another (unrelated) question and was recommended to post the whole class, but I guess what you said makes sense too. I'll update.

Comment: Please see the update, but I failed to reproduce the same results...

Comment: @AndréFratelli: In the question you mentioned you used a total nonstandard class, which is basically totally unknown to most of us ... `article` etc. however is a standard class and does not need to be given here. `\documentclass{article}` would be 'sufficient'

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I'm not sure what you mean, I'm not giving the `article` class here. The original document uses a standard class, yes, but then it was requested in the comments that I post a standalone version and used `article` for that.

Comment: @AndréFratelli: I wanted to prevent you posting the article.cls in addition ;-) And please go back to your other questions -- there are answers to it and some are not accepted yet

Comment: @ChristianHupfer You're right, I accepted the remaining answers. Thank you for the heads up! And got it, I won't post `article.cls` :P

Answer (score 2):

Something similar with `tcolorbox`. The `releasequarter` box is not breakable, though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{10pt}{14pt}\selectfont}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    textheight=650pt,
    headsep=50pt,
    voffset=0pt,
    top=95pt,
    left=39mm,
    right=61mm
}

%\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
%\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Roadmap
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[display]{\bfseries}{\Large\textcolor{gray}{%
    \ifnumcomp{\thesection}{>}{9}{\thesection}{0\thesection}}%
    }{1mm}{\huge}


\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{releaseyear}[2]{%
blanker, breakable, 
     left=5mm, left skip=10.2mm,
     top=-2.2mm,
     coltitle=black,
     attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-12mm, xshift=-13mm},
     fonttitle=\bfseries\Large,
     finish={\draw[#2, line width=3mm,line cap=round]
(frame.south west) -- (frame.north west);},
    title={\rotatebox{90}{#1}}
}
\newtcolorbox{releasequarter}[2]{%
blanker,  
     left=11mm,top=4mm,
          finish={\draw[#2, line width=3mm,line cap=round]
(frame.south west) -- (frame.north west);},
     coltitle=#2,
     attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-4mm},
     fonttitle=\bfseries,
    title={#1}
}


\newcommand{\release}[2]{%
        #1
        \hspace*{\fill}
        \textcolor{gray}{#2}\par}
  
\begin{document}
\section{Roadmap}
    \begin{releaseyear}{2016}{red}
        \begin{releasequarter}{Q1}{red!50}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
        \end{releasequarter}
        \begin{releasequarter}{Q2}{red!50}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
        \end{releasequarter}
        \begin{releasequarter}{Q3}{red!50}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
        \end{releasequarter}
        \begin{releasequarter}{Q4}{red!50}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
        \end{releasequarter}
    \end{releaseyear}
    
    \begin{releaseyear}{2017}{cyan}
        \begin{releasequarter}{Q1}{cyan!50}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
        \end{releasequarter}
        \begin{releasequarter}{Q2}{cyan!50}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
        \end{releasequarter}
        \begin{releasequarter}{Q3}{cyan!50}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
        \end{releasequarter}
        \begin{releasequarter}{Q4}{cyan!50}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
        \end{releasequarter}
    \end{releaseyear}
    
    \begin{releaseyear}{2018}{orange}
        \begin{releasequarter}{Q1}{orange!50}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
        \end{releasequarter}
        \begin{releasequarter}{Q2}{orange!50}
            \release{Feature}{Platf}
            
        \end{releasequarter}
        \begin{releasequarter}{Q3}{orange!30}
        \end{releasequarter}
        \begin{releasequarter}{Q4}{orange!30}
        \end{releasequarter}
    \end{releaseyear}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]